# vb.net how to send sms via gsm to mobile phone from desktop aplication

Tags: vb.net

having difficulties in sending sms via gsm to mobile phone. it giving me this error. CANNOT CONNECT TO PORT COM11. THE REQUESTED RESOURCE IS IN USE. Using windows 7. below is my code

```
            Dim comm = New GsmCommMain("COM11", 460800, 6000)
            TextBox2.Text = "Balance" + "" + Txtbalance.Text
            Dim pdu = New SmsSubmitPdu(TextBox2.Text, Txtcellnumber.Text)
            comm.Open()
            comm.SendMessage(pdu)
            comm.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run your program or visual studio as an Administrator?

Comment: no but i manged to solve the problem by closing all other applications  and restarted my pc